# How to install Scrapy on Mac OS X 10.7 ? (lxml error)

Tags: macos, installation, lxml, scrapy

I'm a total newbie concerning Python and I have trouble installing Scrapy on Mac OS X 10.7. I've tried a lot of different things, but in summary, when I run:

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

I've got these errors :

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___xmlStructuredErrorContext
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
```

After a lot of googling, I've followed [this post](http://roderickhodgson.com/blog/2012/10/27/building-python-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-dot-7/) and tried:

```
python setup.py build --static-deps --libxml2-version=2.7.8  && pip install lxml
```

but it tells me:

```
RuntimeError: ERROR: Trying to build without Cython, but pre-generated 'src/lxml/lxml.etree.c' is not available (pass --without-cython to ignore this error).
```

And if I run the same command with the `—without-cython` option, I get:

```
error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

(though I've  installed XCode command line tools)

Thanks in advance for your help !

(fyi, I am using MacPorts and pip install…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention Macports at the end and also pip. I think you are mixing up packaging and installation methods.

The first import error should not be seen using a macports python as it puts its libraries under /opt/

As you have started on macports I would use the easy way

```
port install py27-scrapy
```

This will install all the needed packages (including python and lxml) to get scrapyto work.

To run scrapy you would need to use the macports python in `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`. This can be set as the default python if /opt/local/bin is on your path and you run port select to choose this as the python found. The scrapy executable script is `/opt/local/bin/scrapy-2.7` Version numbers are used because you can have multiple versions of python working at once.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had `port select --show python`: `The currently selected version for 'python' is 'none'.`
Then I did `sudo port select --set python python27`: 
`Selecting 'python27' for 'python' succeeded. 'python27' is now active.`
Now, I'm able to start a projet typing `sudo /opt/local/bin/scrapy-2.7 startproject tutorial`.